# pingfederate: when import CSR response for digital signing certificate does it replace the original cert immediately?

Tags: digital-certificate, csr, pingfederate

PingFederate 7.3
We have expiring digital signing certificates.  So We generated the CSR from PingFederate under Digital signing certificate -> certificate signing from that particular certificate.

We have submitted the CSR for 3rd party CA to request for the certificate.  The CA has responded with the .p7b file.

So now we are going back to Ping Federate, click on the certificate under Digital signing certificate -> certificate signing from that particular certificate.  This time we selected import CSR.

Question:
After import CSR, done and save.  Does it immediately replace the current certificate that we used to generate CSR, and import?
I have went through the Admin Manual (but it does not mention this part, on the certificate management digital signing certificate section).

Because we need to send this certificate to the SP connection partners first, before replace it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it immediately updates the current signing certificate. You should share the new public key prior to uploading the CSR.

Most federation partners with full federation/SSO applications can support a current/future certificate if they are not using the"anchored " trust model. That way they can load your new cert without breaking the connection.

Quite frankly, for signing, I generally say to use a long-lived self-signed certificate... Like 10-20 years. You only need replace it if standards change or the private key is compromised. You're using it for signing, not encryption.